# How to find AMD graphics card data

Tags: python, gpu

I'm looking to find the utilisation percentage of the core of an AMD graphics card.
I also need to write a function which will output the name of the graphics card, i.e. AMD Radeon R9 380.

I have seen options such as GPUtil which work well for NVIDIA cards.
Here is the function I wrote for the NVIDIA side, to get an idea.

```
    def N_gpu_util_timer(self):
    for n in range(10):
        GPUs = GPUtil.getGPUs()
        gpu_load = GPUs[0].load
        Graph_Util.gpu_y.append(gpu_load)
        Graph_Util.time_x.append(n)
        time.sleep(1)
    print(Graph_Util.gpu_y)
    print('gpu done')
```

Comment: from [this](https://pypi.org/project/GPUtil/) I quote: _"GPUtil is a Python module for getting the GPU status from NVIDA GPUs using nvidia-smi."_ This only works with NVIDIA cards. You need to find some other library/package for AMD.

Comment: It certainly is operating system specific. On Linux the `hwinfo` and `lspci` and `radeontop` commands could be helpful (and you might study their source code for inspiration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [PyADL](https://github.com/nicolargo/pyadl). Using this PyADL library you could get from it `ADLManager.getInstance().getDevices()` and `device.getCurrentUsage()`.

As I mentioned in the comment, *GPUtils* will not work with *AMD* graphics cards. It was written for NVIDIA graphics cards.